# Записать условие задачи с помощью алгебры логики

Tags: математика, логика, дискретная-математика, булева-алгебра

Помогите, пожалуйста, записать условие задачи с помощью алгебры логики.

Три дочери писательницы Дорис Кей — Джуди, Айрис и Линда — тоже очень талантливы. Они приобрели известность в разных видах искусств: пении, балете и кино. Все они живут в разных городах, поэтому Дорис часто звонит им в Париж, Рим и Чикаго. Известно, что: 1.Джуди живет не в Париже, а Линда — не в Риме; 2. парижанка не снимается в кино; 3. та, кто живет в Риме, певица; 4. Линда равнодушна к балету. Где живет Айрис и какова ее профессия?

Вот одно из того, что я пытался сделать. Таблица истинности по такой формуле получается неправильной, как мне кажется.
А – «живет в Париже», В – «живет в Риме», C – «живет в Чикаго», D – «поет», E – «занимается балетом», F – «снимается в кино», G - Джуди, H - Айрис, I - Линда

Джуди живет не в Париже, а Линда - не в Риме; G ^ (B ˅ C) = 1, I ^ (A ˅ C)= 1
парижанка не снимается в кино (парижанка занимается балетом, потому что в Риме – поёт, в Париже – не снимается в кино); A ^ (D ˅ E) = 1
та, которая живет в Риме, певица: B ^ D = 1
Линда не занимается балетом: I ^ (D ˅ F) = 1
Общая формула: G ^ (B ˅ C)^ (I ^ (A ˅ C ))^ A ^ (D ˅ E) ^ (B ^ D) ^ I ^ (D ˅ F) = 1

не исключаю, что написал бред

Comment: Как-то странно. Например, `A` может быть истинным? Обязано, потому что кто-то да живет в Париже. Наверное, нужны более точные высказывания, типа `A - Линда живет в Париже` и так далее, и еще множество условий несовместимости - наподобие `Линда живет в Париже И Линда живет в Чикаго == false`.  А вообще вам надо записать задачу или решить?..

Comment: получается, что у меня будет 6 простых высказываний, из которых я смогу составить одну общую?

Comment: Получается для каждой три высказывания о городе, три - о профессии. Итого (3+3)*3 = 18 высказываний. Плюс утверждения о несовместимости (одна и та же не может жить в одном городже, две не могут заниматься одной профессией и так далее).

Comment: не заметил сначала Ваш вопрос в первом комментарии, поэтому отвечу сейчас: в лабораторной работе 4 задания, и первое из них - это записать условие задачи с помощью алгебры логики; второе - составить таблицу истинности, третье - построить логическую функцию по таблице истинности, четвертое - составить логическую схему. Саму задачу я решил с помощью обыкновенной таблицы с 0 и 1, как в школе, но возникли проблемы с записью алгеброй логики

Comment: Я не учился этому всему, кроме как в детстве почитывал популярные книжечки. Поэтому не уверен, что говорю правильные с точки зрения преподавателей вещит. Так что выслушайте меня, но делайте по-своему ))

Comment: понял) спасибо за Ваши ответы